# set selected value for select element angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select data-ng-model="myclass" data-ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
        <option value="">-- Select Freight Class --</option>
    </select>
</body>

    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$http', '$scope', '$filter', function ($http, $scope, $filter) {
    $scope.myclass = {
        "name": "65"
    };
    $scope.colors = [{
        name: '50'
    }, {
        name: '55'
    }, {
        name: '105'
    }, {
        name: '110'
    }, {
        name: '400'
    }, {
        name: '500'
    }];

}]);
```

as you can see I am trying to set default selected value of this select as `65` but its not working. Can any one tell me how to achieve this?
http://jsfiddle.net/d8kg0uys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't have `{"name": "65"}` object in `colors` array at all. But even if you tried to select option `{"name": "55"}` it would not work. And the reason is because `$scope.myclass` is not equal to any element in `colors` array.

Angular compares objects to set corresponding option as selected, and one object equals to another only when it's *the same* object. So to correctly set selected value you have to provide a *reference* to an object in `colors` array:

```
$scope.myclass = $scope.colors[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by:

```
$scope.myclass = $scope.colors[1];
```

please see here http://jsfiddle.net/9d0f8sdj/1/

Answer (score 1):

See [AngularJS Reference for Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#example); You do this by selecting the index of the value you want:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$filter',
        function ($http, $scope, $filter) {

            $scope.colors = [{
                name: '50'
            }, {
                name: '55'
            }, {
                name: '65'
            }, {
                name: '105'
            }, {
                name: '110'
            }, {
                name: '400'
            }, {
                name: '500'
            }];

            $scope.myclass = $scope.colors[2];

        }]);
```

So, the value you want should also be in the `$scope.colors` list, like I added it above.

Your fiddle corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/d8kg0uys/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are binding an object to the ng-model, not the object's field. Not that that is bad but comparing objects in javascript is not as simple as it is in other languages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/1264360

Also 65 is not in your options list so it is defaulting to the default value.

```
<select data-ng-model="myclass.name" data-ng-options="color.name as color.name for color in colors">
    <option value="">-- Select Freight Class --</option>
</select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YLFgjILNUC0RP2aBAT6q?p=preview